# New Pandas dataframe from old dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new dataframe for future processing from an existing dataframe created from a database.  I have what seems like a workable solution, but there has to be a better way.

I need to make a new dataframe that captures key rows associated with a specific obj_id

Old dataframe:

| obj_id | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | weight | 150 |
| 1 | height | 5.8 |
| 1 | eye_color | blue |
| 2 | weight | 160 |

Desired New dataframe:

| obj_id | weight |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 150 |
| 2 | 160 |
| 3 | 140 |
| 4 | 150 |

There are ~5-10 column B (label) to column C (value) combinations I'll need to capture and turn into their own columns from the old database

This seems to work but its seems a bit clunky

```
import pandas as pd

# old dataframe = df_2
# new dataframe = df

def myfunction(row):
     new_id = row[obj_id]
     for index, rows in df_2.iterrows():
         if new_id in rows['obj_id"]
            if "weight" in rows['Column B']:
                return rows['Column C']

df['weight'] = df.apply(myfunction, axis=1)
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is your code supposed to be `row['obj_id']`? And what is `df_2`?

Comment: Yes!  Fixed it, sorry for making it more confusing than needed

Comment: The code you have doesn't create the output you have tried to outline. There is no `obj_id` other than 1 and 2. Are you just trying to create a new dataframe of the same size that has `obj_id = 1..4` and `Column_b = 'x'`?

Comment: Yes, there are going to be a few hundred obj_id's.  Each with a column_b = 'x' combination that I want to make into a new dataframe.  There are roughly 20 Column_B to Column C combinations for each obj_id where the Column B value is basically the label for the Column C value.  I'll need to create new columns for about 5 or 6 of these label/value combinations in the new dataframe.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible and meaningful example. If the `x`s in the output are not literal, please [edit] to demonstrate what you expect with a real example. Also, clearly explain why there are IDs 3/4 in the output. The provided output should match exactly what you would expect from a working code, not be a dummy example.

Comment: Ok.  I edited it to give a more real example.  Hope this helps what I'm trying to capture

Comment: @Chris where are the weight 140, 160, and ids 3, 4 coming from in your output? I believe you're not showing the full thing.

Comment: @mozway.  Apologies for the confusion, and no, I'm not showing the actual data, just what I'm trying to use to illustrate the system.  In reality, the old dataframe has many tens of thousands of obj_id's, with many B(label) to C(value) combinations.  I was trying to illustrate that like a screenshot in my examples.  So the obj_id's 3 and 4 were just below 1 and 2, and you can assume that they all have roughly the same B->C combinations.

Comment: @Chris you should always provide a [mre] with the expected output that **matches the given input**, this avoids confusion. Here this would be just the first two rows of the output. If I understood correctly, you need to filter then `pivot`. Note that I named the input `df` in my answer below and the output `out`.

Comment: Roger, will be a bit more careful next time.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter the rows for which "Column B" is equal to "weight", then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
out = (df.query('`Column B` == "weight"')
         .pivot(index='obj_id', columns='Column B',
                values='Column C')
         .astype({'weight': int}) # optional
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
       )
```

Or, if you are potentially interested in keeping other categories than just "weight":

```
keep = ['weight'] # if you want other categories add them here

out = (df.loc[lambda d: d['Column B'].isin(keep)]
         .pivot(index='obj_id', columns='Column B',
                values='Column C')
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
       )
```

A less efficient alternative would be to `pivot` first, then select the columns to keep. This however can generate an unnecessarily wide intermediate if there are many unwanted categories:

```
keep = ['weight']
out = (df.pivot(index='obj_id', columns='Column B',
                values='Column C')[keep]
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
       )
```

Output:

```
   obj_id weight
0       1    150
1       2    160
```

Comment: Hadn't considered making a quick pivot table!  Great solution, thank you!